# Normalizing nested json data with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I am trying to work with a nested json and I am not reaching the result that I want.

I have a JSON data like this:

```
{'from_cache': True,
 'results': [{'data': [{'date': '2019/06/01', 'value': 0},
                   {'date': '2019/06/02', 'value': 0},
                   {'date': '2019/08/09', 'value': 7087},
                   {'date': '2019/08/10', 'value': 0},
                   {'date': '2019/08/11', 'value': 15},
                   {'date': '2019/08/12', 'value': 14177},
                   {'date': '2019/08/13', 'value': 0}],
          'name': 'Clicks'},
     {'data': [{'date': '2019/06/01', 'value': 0.0},
                   {'date': '2019/06/02', 'value': 0.0},
                   {'date': '2019/06/03', 'value':1.0590561064390611},
                   {'date': '2019/08/11', 'value':1.8610421836228286},
                   {'date': '2019/08/12', 'value': 6.191613785151832},
                   {'date': '2019/08/13', 'value': 0.0}],
          'name': 'Rate'}]}
```

The expected result is a dataframe like this:

```
date         Clicks   Rate
2019/06/01   0        0.0
2019/06/02   0        0.0
2019/08/09   7087     1.0590561064390611
```

As you can see I want each 'name' as a dataframe column with the respective 'values'.

I am working with pd.io.json_normalize, but no success to get this result. The best result I've reached is a dataframe with the columns: date, value, name.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `pd.concat` through `axis=1`

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(k['data']).rename(columns={'value': k['name']})\
                                       .set_index('date') 
                for k in d['results']], 
                sort=False, 
                axis=1)
```

---

```
             Clicks      Rate
2019/06/01      0.0  0.000000
2019/06/02      0.0  0.000000
2019/08/09   7087.0       NaN
2019/08/10      0.0       NaN
2019/08/11     15.0  1.861042
2019/08/12  14177.0  6.191614
2019/08/13      0.0  0.000000
2019/06/03      NaN  1.059056
```

---

Another way with `pivot_table`

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x['data']).assign(column=x['name']) for x in d['results']])\
       .pivot_table(columns='column', index='date', values='value')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Without loops:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = json_normalize(data['results'], record_path=['data'], meta=['name'])    
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df_clicks = df[df.name == 'Clicks'].drop('name', axis=1).rename(columns={'value': 'Clicks'})
df_rate = df[df.name == 'Rate'].drop('name', axis=1).rename(columns={'value': 'Rate'})

df_final = df_clicks.merge(df_rate, how='outer', sort=True)
df_final.set_index('date', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

[image]

- unexpected data:

  - 2019-06-03: a rate with no clicks
  - 2019-08-09: clicks, but no rate

### Plot it:

```
df_final.plot(kind='bar', logy=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Suggested new json format:

```
data = {'from_cache': True,
        'results': [{'date': '2019/06/01', 'Clicks': 0, 'Rate': 0},
                    {'date': '2019/06/02', 'Clicks': 0, 'Rate': 0},
                    {'date': '2019/06/03', 'Clicks': 0, 'Rate': 1.0590561064390611},
                    {'date': '2019/08/09', 'Clicks': 7087, 'Rate': 0},
                    {'date': '2019/08/10', 'Clicks': 0, 'Rate': 0},
                    {'date': '2019/08/11', 'Clicks': 15, 'Rate': 1.8610421836228286},
                    {'date': '2019/08/12', 'Clicks': 14177, 'Rate': 6.191613785151832},
                    {'date': '2019/08/13', 'Clicks': 0, 'Rate': 0}]}
```

Comment: It is really a great solution! Thank you so much for your help!